# ZF2+Doctrine2 - Suddenly getting error on Mac: "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"; no instance returned

Tags: php, macos, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am working on building a Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) website using Doctrine2 DBAL/ORM, where I develop equally on Windows and Mac, sometimes Linux (Ubuntu) (I like the all-around experience).

In `composer.json` I have the following versions:

- "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "^0.9.1"
- "zendframework/zendframework": ">=2.3.2,<3.0.0"

At first, my website ran fine on all three environments using XAMPP (Apache 2.4.16, MySQL 5.0.11, and PHP 5.6.12). But suddenly, after I performed some changes on Windows and pulled those changes from GitHub to my Mac computer, Doctrine started failing with the following exception message:

```
An exception was raised while creating "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"; no instance returned
```

I got this exception a lot while configuring Doctrine2 in ZF2. But once I was done, things just worked. That is until it broke on Mac, only! It still works fine on Windows.

I have cleared the cache completely (`rm data/cache/*`) and I have verified the integrity of my configuration files. The only difference in configuration between Windows and Mac is that I provide a `unix_socket`path for MySQL (see below).

My `config/application.php`:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        // ...
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        // ...
    ),
);
```

My `config/autoload/databases.local.php` looks like this (with changed values for database server login information):

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'unix_socket' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock', // This is for Mac
                    'host'        => 'some_host',
                    'port'        => '3306',
                    'user'        => 'some_user',
                    'password'    => 'some_password',
                    'dbname'      => 'some_database',
                )
            )
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'proxy_dir' => 'core/server/data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

As mentioned, these configurations work on Windows (I can retrieve and use the EntityManager) and is a 1:1 mirror onto my Mac solution. So what happens?

When I check the cached configuration file, `data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php`, on my Mac, the database login informations are incorrect, having the following values:

```
// ...
array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3306',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname' => 'database',
),
// ...
```

Obviously these are wrong. But how can ZF2 suddenly generate incorrect configurations on Mac?

I even tried checkout out previous commits from Git on my Mac, which I know worked for certain. But the same problem occurs. The only difference, I suspect might have influence on this behavior, is that I ran `composer.phar update`, which might've changed the versions of ZF2 and/or Doctrine2.

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate proxies by running `orm:generate-proxies`?

Comment: @StoryTeller I removed the proxies, too, from the `data` folder (`data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy`). It's not getting as far as to even generating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boiled down to the glob pattern for the autoload config files being incorrect.

```
$appConfig['module_listener_options']['config_glob_paths'][$index] = getcwd() . '/' . $path;
```

`getcwd()` had an incorrect pointer, despite having specified the following:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../..'));
chdir(ROOT_PATH);
```

For some reason I cannot fathom, it worked before on Windows and Ubuntu, but not on Mac. Now it works in all three environments.

It's an almost invisible error and required line-by-line debugging through the bootstrapping logic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error message were thrown, when the database was missing!